# Transforming bookmarks to data driven pages in ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages, bookmarks

We have this large project in ArcGIS with 30 maps with different extents using Bookmarks to pan between these maps/pages.

Now we would like to use Data driven pages instead.

Is it possible to convert bookmarks to data driven pages or do we have to create a lot of polygons covering each map extent?

Answer (score 8):

Not directly, but you can do this with python and the arcpy.mapping module. Use [arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000060000000) to get the extent of each bookmark. Then create features for each extent. You will now be able to use this feature class as the index layer for Data Driven Pages.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be far from alone in wanting this as Out-Of-The-Box functionality.  There are at least three ArcGIS Ideas that I would recommend you add your name to:

- [Bookmarks for MapBook](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008FVZAA2) - which is Under Consideration
- [Bookmarks for DataDriven Maps](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bq2AAAQ) - which has a comment from Chris Fox that "At 10.1 you will be able to do this through python as you can utilize the new ListBookmarks function to return a list of extents of your bookmarks and in a loop adjust the extent of your data frame based on the extent of each bookmark."
- [Layer to Bookmarks Tool & Bookmarks to Layer Tool](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008JNVAA2)

In the meantime if someone is inspired to write a **BookMarks To Feature Class** tool, then I am sure its output would be well used as an Index Feature Class for Data Driven Pages.

I ended up doing this as a Training exercise based heavily on some Sample Code the ArcGIS Online Help for ListBookmarks (arcpy.mapping).

```
import arcpy

# The map with the bookmarks
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\polygeo\Maps\Bookmarks.mxd")

# Make sure that Training.gdb exists
fileGDBFolder = (r"C:\polygeo")
fileGDBName = ("Training.gdb")
fileGDB = fileGDBFolder + "\\" + fileGDBName
if not arcpy.Exists(fileGDB):
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(fileGDBFolder, fileGDBName)

# The output feature class to be created -
# This feature class will store the bookmarks as features
fcName = "Bookmarks"
outFC = fileGDB + "\\" + fcName

# Create new feature class and add a "Name" field to store the
# bookmark name.  Provide it with the same Spatial reference as
# the data frame in which the bookmarks of the map are stored

if arcpy.Exists(outFC):
    arcpy.Delete_management(outFC)   
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(fileGDB,
                                    fcName, 
                                    "POLYGON", 
                                    spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(
                                        "Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994"))
arcpy.AddField_management(outFC, "Name", "TEXT", "", "", 50)

# Use arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks to read bookmark corners and names,
# then arcpy.da.InsertCursor to write arrays of Point geometries from
# that can be written as Polygon geometries to the Shape field of the
# new feature class (with their names).
cur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFC, ["SHAPE@", "Name"])
array = arcpy.Array()
for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd):
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMax))
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMax, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    # To close the polygon, add the first point again
    array.add(arcpy.Point(bkmk.extent.XMin, bkmk.extent.YMin))
    cur.insertRow([arcpy.Polygon(array), bkmk.name])
    array.removeAll()
del bkmk,array,cur,mxd

print "Bookmarks feature class has been created in " + fileGDB
```

---

I should be noted that ArcGIS Pro (also part of ArcGIS Desktop) has Map Series which can be generated direct from Bookmarks.  For more details see [Introduction to a bookmark map series](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/bookmark-map-series.htm).

Answer (score 3):

We were able to create a feature class by saving out the bookmarks as a .dat file then load that file into the **My Places** tool, then select them within the My Places dialog box, then click the **Add To** button and chose **Map As Graphic** Once you have a graphic then select all graphics within the map and use the **Convert Graphics to Features** then you can use the Feature Class for Data Driven Pages. Note: the Graphics came through as polygons. All credit goes to Seneca Francis.