# Creating polygons or map book from DBF file through ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy, polygon-creation, dbf, map-book

I have a dbf file, which contained a list of coordinate information as shown in below. It also could be thought as a catalog file. Example:

```
ID   XMIN       YMIN      XMAX       YMAX
1  -52800.0   -63000.0  -52000.0   -62400.0
2  -48800.0   -60600.0  -48000.0   -60000.0
3  -48800.0   -61200.0  -48000.0   -60600.0
4  -49600.0   -61800.0  -48800.0   -61200.0
5  -48800.0   -61800.0  -48000.0   -61200.0
```

So, how can i extract these information to create shapes or a map book as the picture shown in below. Using Python.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most, probably all, of the code that you will need to do this plus some more is available in my answer to [Transform bookmarks to data driven pages in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33237)

If it does not help you get all the way there, then I recommend posting a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it seems useful, but the method of bookmark is a little difficult to make sense. Otherwise, how can i create a polygon with coordinate of XMIN, YMIN, XMAX, YMAX automatically through Python?

Comment: That sounds like a much simpler question that I think you should research/ask separately. First work out how to read the values from the DBF using a search cursor and simply print them. Separately work out how to write one set of coordinates to a polygon feature class. Finally, put the two halves together by incorporating an insert cursor to write multiple polygons.

Comment: Yes, this make sense, u r incredible right! So, to write coordinates to a polygon feature, insert cursor will be enough? Ok, i'll try, thank you very much!